# Ошибка Python TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python

Как починить эту ошибку? У меня есть отдельный файл input.txt там заложены значения. Мне надо что бы каждое число из второй строчки файла применялось к переменной A. Скорее всего число в переменной A записано как строковый объект или же переменной присваивается пробел(если такое возможно). До ошибки выводится первая цифра из 2-й строки файла.

Пример input.txt

5

5 1 2 3 6

Ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\1\python\AFff\melons4.py", line 10, in <module>
    if A > B:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Код

```
    inp = open(r"C:\Users\1\python\input.txt")
    output = open(r"C:\Users\1\python\output.txt", "w")
    N = int(inp.readline())
    B=0
    C=30000
    i=1
    for i in range (0, N):
        A = inp.read(1)
        print(A)
        if A > B:
            B = A
        if A < C:
            C = A
    
    output.write(C, B)
    inp.close()
    output.close()
```

Comment: Очевидно, `A` это строка, а строку нельзя сравнивать с числом. Как починить — преобразовать в число.

Comment: @andreymal я догадывался до этого, но мой способ  A = int(inp.read(1)) не работает

Comment: Потому что `inp.read(1)` может оказаться пробелом.

Comment: Ладно, я сделал int(inp.read(2)) и это работает. Спасибо.